# Textbook recommendation renewable energy

Tags: resource-recommendations, renewable-energy

I am supposed to teach a lecture on the broad field of renewable energy for the first time. I wanted to check how other people cover the field, but there is a plethora of books on the subject and even the subject itself is a broad category.

Is there any kind of "standard textbook", that i should be aware of? I would also be happy on opinions, that state what makes a "good" textbook that covers the field.

Comment: I have found that there is a **big** difference in how people "talk" about the subject when they have their own pv and solar systems (or wind, hydro etc) and those who have never seen or used a system based on renewables...

Comment: In my opinion, a good text book will point out the advantages and disadvantages of renewable energy, do the same thing for fossil fuels, and discuss both the practical and political aspects for why it is so difficult to eliminate fossil fuels.